# Difficulty find within array names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array that has several people, each with a phone number.
I want to save the names in the result variable when I type part of the name, either in uppercase or lowercase, and click the search button, and circle the results in the `showResultSearch` function and display them on the console.
Please help me to get the result

*I want to get the result as I wrote it and use the `this` keyword in writing the function I want to get the result this way*

```js
  this.array = [
        { name: "Niloufar", phone: 123456 }, { name: "sara", phone: 123456 },
        { name: "Amir", phone: 123456 }, { name: "arman", phone: 123456 },
        { name: "Paria", phone: 123456 }, { name: "nadiya", phone: 123456 }
    ];

    const self = this
    this.search = function search() {
        function filterArray() {
            const selectInput = document.getElementById("inputSearch").value;
            const result = self.array.find(item => item.name === selectInput);
            if (result === undefined) {
                alert("No search results found");
            }
        }
        return filterArray;
    }
    this.showResultSearch = function () {
        const searchResult = self.search;
        searchResult.forEach(ele => {
            console.log(`name: ${ele.name} phone: ${ele.name}`)
        })
    }
    this.startSearch = function () {
        this.search();
        this.showResultSearch();
    }
```

```html
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="inputSearch">
        <button type="button" id="BtnSearch" onclick="this.startSearch">Search</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

1. use filter instead of find.
2. use toUpperCase() for both comparing values
3. use includes instead of ===

   ```
        this.array = [
            { name: "Niloufar", phone: 123456 },
            { name: "sara", phone: 123456 },
            { name: "Amir", phone: 123456 },
            { name: "arman", phone: 123456 },
            { name: "Paria", phone: 123456 },
            { name: "nadiya", phone: 123456 },
        ];
        const self = this;
        this.search = function search() {
            function filterArray() {
                const selectInput = document.getElementById("inputSearch").value;
                const result = self.array.filter((obj) => {
                return obj.name.toUpperCase().includes(selectInput.toUpperCase())} );
                if (result === undefined || selectInput==="") {
                    alert("No search results found");
                }
                return result;
            }
            return filterArray();
        };
        this.showResultSearch = function () {
            const searchResult = self.search();
            searchResult.forEach((ele) => {
                console.log(`name: ${ele.name} phone: ${ele.phone}`);
            });
        };
        this.startSearch = function () {
            console.clear();
            this.showResultSearch();
        };
   ```

Comment: Thank you dear friend, your code works
But the point is that I want the previous results to be deleted every time I search for a new result
In this code, when the input is empty, I want alear to be displayed, but when the input is clicked, all the people in the display array

Comment: @good you mean clear from the console? or remove from the array?

Comment: No I want to delete the previous results from the console and display the aleart message when the input is empty and we click

Comment: Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Edited the code. included  console.clear();

Answer (score 1):

The `Array.find` callback is passed an object from your array, so in this place:

```
self.array.find(name => name === selectInput);
```

you are comparing `{ name: "Niloufar", phone: 123456 }` to a string.

You can either write it this way:

```
self.array.find(item => item.name === selectInput);
```

or destructure the argument:

```
self.array.find( ({ name }) => name === selectInput);
```

Comment: Excuse me, my dear friend, I'm confused. Please edit my code correctly if possible. Thank you.

Comment: I did, but the result is not displayed on the console